# How to add a such title as in attached picture

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to add a title like in the picture as follows. How to make it? Thanks!

[image]

I try to use the code:

````
\center
\colorbox{yellow}{\color{black}Part I: Wigner matrices and a general Talagrand-type theorem}
\end{frame}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) provides the `block` environment. If you specify no title (an empty mandatory argument), the representation matches what you're showing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame title}
  
  \begin{block}{}
    \centering
    Part I: Wigner matrices and a general Talagrand-type theorem
  \end{block}
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tcolorbox` to get fancy boxes.

```
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames]{beamer}                                                 
%
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{%
    calc, arrows.meta, through, backgrounds, intersections, angles,
    quotes, shapes.geometric, decorations.text, bending, positioning,
    decorations.markings, decorations.footprints, snakes }
  \tikzset{>=Stealth}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\mode<presentation>{
                  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}

  \tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
  \tcbset{enhanced,drop fuzzy shadow}                                                     
                                                                                          
\begin{document}                                                                          
                                                                                          
\begin{frame}                                                                             
\frametitle{FrameTitle}                                                                   
                                                                                          
  \begin{tcolorbox}[drop shadow, colback=Cornsilk]                                        
    Part I: Wigner matrices and a general Talagrand-type theorem.                         
  \end{tcolorbox}                                                                         
                                                                                          
\end{frame}                                                                               
                                                                                          
\end{document}
```

[image]